# SQL Server : query to get multiple results in one field

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, syntax, join

I have 2 SQL Server tables

**equip_info**

```
equip_id | asset_no
-------------------
1        | CAL-1 
2        | MIC-1
...
```

**equip_insp**

```
insp_id | equip_id | insp_name   | due_date
----------------------------------------------
1       | 1        | Calibration | 2014-01-10
2       | 1        | Maintenance | 2014-01-10
3       | 1        | Check       | 2014-02-10
4       | 2        | Calibration | 2014-11-04
5       | 2        | Maintenance | 2014-05-04
...
```

`equip_id` doesn't have 2 similar `insp_name`, but this is less important.

In one sentence, I would like to help me with the T-SQL syntax for getting a list of distinct equipments and with the "next" inspection or inspections (if due_date's are the same) and the due_date.

It could be the case when for the same due_date there are several inspections, so in this case this must be concatenated and shown in one field (ex: "Calibration, Maintenance")

Result of this query should be something like:

```
equip_id | asset_no | inspection               | due_date
-----------------------------------------------------------
1        | CAL-1    | Calibration, Maintenance | 2014-01-10
2        | MIC-1    | Maintenance              | 2014-05-04
```

Comment: join both the tables. search google about join and read. You can solve your question.

Comment: Why the `Check` insp_name is not included in your result table?

Comment: Because the `due_date` for 'Check' is not the earliest / next due date. The earliest `due_date` for `equip_id = 1` is `10/01/2014`

Comment: @Shiva So you need the earlest `due_date` for each `equip_id` and distinct `insp_name` in CSV list for this `due_date`?

Comment: Yes, looks like that's what the `OP` wants. I built the schema and populated the table. Here's the fiddle, if you wanna work off of it and finish this exercise :) http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/4fdff/2

Comment: @Shiva Thanks, man :D for spending time to generate sample data.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/43892/discussion-between-gotqn-and-shiva)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the SqlFiddle of [@Shiva](https://stackoverflow.com/users/325521/shiva):

```
create table equip_info (
  equip_id int not null,
   asset_no nvarchar(10) not null
  );

insert into equip_info (equip_id, asset_no) values
(1, 'CAL-1'),
(2, 'MIC-1');

create table equip_insp (
  insp_id  int not null,
  equip_id  int not null,
  insp_name nvarchar(50) not null,
  due_date datetime not null
  );

insert into equip_insp values
(1,1,'Calibration','10/01/2014'),
(2,1,'Maintenance','10/01/2014'),
(3,1,'Check','10/02/2014'),
(4,2,'Calibration','04/11/2014'),
(5,2,'Maintenance','04/05/2014');
```

This is what you need:

```
;WITH DataSource AS
(
  select inf.equip_id
        ,asset_no
        ,MIN(due_date) as [due_date]
  from equip_info inf
  inner join equip_insp ins
    on inf.[equip_id] = ins.[equip_id]
  GROUP BY inf.equip_id
          ,asset_no
)
SELECT equip_id
      ,asset_no
      ,SUBSTRING((SELECT DISTINCT ', ' + insp_name 
        FROM equip_insp 
        WHERE due_date = DS.due_date
          AND equip_id = DS.equip_id
        FOR XML PATH('')
       ),2,4000) as inspection
      ,due_date
FROM DataSource DS
```

This is the ouput:

[image]

[Here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/4fdff/38) is the full working example.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT DISTINCT   Ins.equip_id
               ,  info.asset_no
               , STUFF(List.Inspections, 1 , 2, '') AS Inspections
               , ins.due_date 
FROM #equip_insp Ins INNER JOIN #equip_info Info
ON Ins.equip_id = info.equip_id CROSS APPLY 
                                    (
                                    SELECT ', ' + insp_name [text()]
                                    FROM #equip_insp
                                    WHERE equip_id = Ins.equip_id
                                    AND due_date = Ins.due_date
                                    FOR XML PATH('')
                                    ) List(Inspections)
```

**Results**

```
equip_id    asset_no    Inspections                     due_date
1           CAL-1       Calibration, Maintenance    2014-10-01 00:00:00.000
1           CAL-1       Check                       2014-10-02 00:00:00.000
2           MIC-1       Calibration                 2014-04-11 00:00:00.000
2           MIC-1       Maintenance                 2014-04-05 00:00:00.000
```